# Why strrev on "ç" transform into "?"

Tags: php

Why when I use strrev ("ç") for reverse a string, the string "ç" reverse transforms into an interrogation point?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4S66.png)
Do you know why ?.
I try "salut ça va", return "av a?? tulas"  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iadxb.png)

Comment: It's about muiltibyte encoding. https://3v4l.org/bWpvI

Comment: Because `strrev` doesn't understand multibyte encoding so you just reversed the two bytes that the `ç` consisted of, creating two garbage characters instead. The gargabe characters were then rendered as question marks.